# Write to a location that is visible in tests from Apex

Tags: unit-test, standard-objects

Is there any object in Salesforce that is writeable from Apex (without the Metadata API) that is visible in apex tests regardless of apex test isolation? For example, we can read from JSON stored in a static resource, but cannot edit a static resource without the metadata api.

The basic use case is to configure some test setup from Apex that is then visible to tests (the apex is running in system mode and kicked off from another event, but the running user may not have metadata api access). Most of our configuration is stored in custom settings but as you know, these are not visible in apex tests.

Comment: You can maybe try using [Custom Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/05/testing-custom-metadata-types.html)!

Comment: Users are visible and writeable. Would be a horrible hack to use a custom field on User for testing though

Comment: Not quite sure why @TestSetup is inappropriate here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SebastianKessel the tests are running in a different org than they were developed in. There is some extensive configuration available and we would like to make some decisions when running tests in the target org based on some of that configuration. The tests already cover an extensive set of configuration options, but some of the options are very open-ended and we would like to be able to grab some of that information to run some very informed test cases when in an installed org. Note that this was developed before custom metadata so the configuration is stored in protected custom settings.

Comment: @RahulSharma Custom Metadata Types are not writable without the Metadata API, are they? I can't find anything saying they support direct DML statements.

Comment: I don't see any other way than to either do SeeAllData = true (please please please please don't) or to re-create those custom settings in a @TestSetup context.

Comment: @SebastianKessel unfortunately we can't recreate the data because the tests are managed and the configuration is in the subscriber org (which means we can't know what it is to create it from the test context). It sounds like this might just not be possible on that platform which would be very disappointing.

Comment: It's a philosophical discussion and, I said before, context is king, but normally it's the packagers responsibility to test with all possible scenarios the package allows instead of depending on the individual subscriber's config to do so.

Not sure how practical this is in your case, but the idea should be that you cover most of potential cases in your testing